# How watch values doesn't affect the environment

Tags: debugging, ide, watch

When debugging in IDE, how does the IDE know how to calculate the watch value without changing the environment (writing to file, writing result to DB)?

[image: Watch Expression Screenshot]

Comment: Which IDE? Which programming language? The image does not show the result of the evaluation.

Comment: I tried to make it a general question as possible. (in this case it is intellij and java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation cannot be generalized. An IDE typically makes changes during debugging, especially if a property has a side effect.

### Visual Studio

The following C# code:

```
using System;

namespace EvaluateChangesValue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var program = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(program.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(program.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private int member;

        private int Value => member++;
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint at the first `ReadLine()`, then add `program.Value` to the watch window and see how the value gets increased due to the `member++` statement.

[image: Visual Studio changed value]

### Eclipse

In Java and Eclipse, it's a bit harder to make the same proof because for these reasons:

1. In Java it's more clear whether you call a method or access a field.
2. You need the "Expressions" window, which is not available by default
3. Re-evaluation needs user interaction

The code is similar to C#:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        System.out.println(p.member);
        System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println(p.member);
        System.console().readLine();
    }

    private int member;

    public int getMember()
    {
        return member++;
    }
}
```

And the screenshot:

[image: Changed value in Eclipse]

Comment: It probably also happens on Java and other IDEs.

Comment: Is this means that each time I'm doing a next, the watch will be recalculate and program.Value will be increased?

Comment: So it means, debugging can have a different result than regular running

Comment: @omer727: yes, debugging an application can cause different results. Often due to timeouts, but in this case also for values. I have installed Eclipse now and I'll try to repeat the example there.

Comment: Thanks for such enormous investment. But if you are continue to use java, try idea intellij it's a lot better